# React Informed eslint associated control error after adding "Text" as control component

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lint

I am trying to add the `informed` package to my project, but I am getting the eslint an error when I add the components like this:

```
    <Form id="intro-form">
      <label htmlFor="intro-name">
        First name:
        <Text field="name" id="intro-name" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
```

I have added `Text` to my `.eslintrc` as a `controlComponent` and I am still getting the error:

`eslint] Form label must have ALL of the following types of associated control: nesting, id (jsx-a11y/label-has-for)`

I'm guessing this is not the correct way to add this to my `.eslintrc` file?

```
{
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [ 2, {
        "labelComponents": ["label"],
        "labelAttributes": ["htmlFor"],
        "controlComponents": ["Text"]
      }]
  },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
      "airbnb"
    ]
  }
```

When I change `Text` to `input` the error goes away, so it feels like I'm misunderstanding how this works. Any suggestions for how to allow `Text` as an acceptable `input`?

Comment: How did you go about solving this?

Comment: @kellymandem Unfortunately, I didn't. It's still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[label-has-for](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md) was deprecated in v6.1.0. Use [label-has-associated-control](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md) instead.

> drop deprecated rule

```json
// .eslintrc
"rules": {
  "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": "off",
  "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [ 2, {
    "labelComponents": [ "Label" ],
    "labelAttributes": ["label"],
    "required": "either"
  }]
}
```

However, to provide an answer, the components option determine which JSX elements should be checked for having `htmlFor` prop, which in your case is unclear from info provided.

> deprecated rule: for some

```js
// .eslintrc
"rules": {
  "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 2, {
    "components": [ "Label" ],
    "required": {
      "some": [ "nesting", "id" ]
    }
  }]
}

// Label component
const Label = ({htmlFor, label}) => <label htmlFor={htmlFor}>{label}</label>

// usage
<Label htmlFor="test" label="label" />
<input id="test"></input>
```

> deprecated rule: for every

```js
// .eslintrc
"jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 2, {
  ...
  "required": {
    "every": [ "nesting", "id" ]
  }
}]

// usage
<Label htmlFor="test" label="label">
  <input id="test"></input>
</Label>
```