# How to resolve "A control must be associated with a text label" on a datalist's option?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, bootstrap-5, formik

Building a dropdown and referencing Bootstrap 5 docs' on [Datalists](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists) it shows an example of:

```
<label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
  <option value="San Francisco">
  <option value="New York">
  <option value="Seattle">
  <option value="Los Angeles">
  <option value="Chicago">
</datalist>
```

Writing my component to handle drop downs I'm unsure how to resolve the ESLint error of:

> A control must be associated with a text label

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Field } from 'formik'

const Drop = ({ name, label, id, placeholder, options }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group mb-4">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}:</label>
      <Field
        aria-label={`${name}-dropdown`}
        name={name}
        className="form-control"
        list={id}
        id={`${id}DropDown`}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      <datalist id={id}>
        {options.map((option, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={option.toString()} data-value={option.toString()} />
        ))}
      </datalist>
    </div>
  )
}

Drop.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default Drop
```

### Research

- [React Informed eslint associated control error after adding "Text" as control component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595264/react-informed-eslint-associated-control-error-after-adding-text-as-control-co)
- [A control must be associated with a text label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367013/a-control-must-be-associated-with-a-text-label)
- [Label must have associated control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306461/label-must-have-associated-control)

In my `option` how can I resolve the ESLint error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding an `aria-label` to the `option` so this:

```
<datalist id={id}>
  {options.map((option, key) => (
    <option key={key} value={option.toString()} data-value={option.toString()} />
  ))}
</datalist>
```

turned into:

```
<datalist id={id}>
  {options.map((option, key) => (
    <option key={key} value={option.toString()} aria-label={option.toString()} data-value={option.toString()} />
  ))}
</datalist>
```

after going through the docs and finding [control-has-associated-label](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/control-has-associated-label.md).